# SQL Having Clause with Partitioned Aggregates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm wondering if there is a way to do the following query with a single `select`.

```
select
    z.a,
    z.SumB
from (
    select
        X.a,
        sum(X.b) over (partition by X.a) as SumB
    from (
        values
            ('hello',1),
            ('hello',2),
            ('goodbye',1)
    ) as X(a,b)
) as z
where
    z.SumB > 1
;
```

My thought is that the query might be better optimized if I could eliminate those rows sooner.

The following query doesn't work.

```
select
    X.a,
    sum(X.b) over (partition by X.a)
from (
    values
        ('hello',1),
        ('hello',2),
        ('goodbye',1)
) as X(a,b)
having
     sum(X.b) over (partition by X.a) > 1
;
```

> Msg 8121, Level 16, State 1, Line 11 Column 'X.a' is invalid in the
> HAVING clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate
> function or the GROUP BY clause.
>
> Msg 4108, Level 15, State 1, Line 11 Windowed functions can only
> appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses.

Is there a better way to limit these results in the base query?

Comment: No, you'll need a subquery or CTE to achieve this. You can't use an `OVER` clause in the `WHERE`, and `HAVING` requires non-windowed aggregate functions.

Answer (score 2):

```
select
 X.a,
 SUM(x.B)
from (
  values
   ('hello',1),
   ('hello',2),
   ('goodbye',1)
  ) as X(a,b)
GROUP BY X.a
HAVING SUM(b)>1
```

Comment: This would give the same results as the (simplified) example, however the windowing is much more complex and crucial in the real query.

Comment: If windowing is important, you can add on the select a “COUNT(1) NumberOfInstances”. Otherwise, it will require at least 2 selects to get the window.

Answer (score 1):

you can try like below

```
with cte as

(
select
    X.a,
    sum(X.b) over (partition by X.a) as total
from (
    values
        ('hello',1),
        ('hello',2),
        ('goodbye',1)
) as X(a,b)
) select * from cte where total>1
```

Comment: Isn't this the same, but with a CTE instead of a subquery? There's still 2 `SELECT` clauses in the above and the OP was specifically trying to do it with 1.